# Testcomplete obj.$get("attrName") vs obj.attrName

Tags: javascript, xml, testcomplete

I am working on a projet in Testcomplete 12.0.122 with javascript. I have a problem when I read an XML file and create a CSV file with the needed data.

Reading xml with **Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0**

Write in CSV with **aqFile.OpenTextFile**

When the XML file is quite huge (above 200Mo) the execution start to take long (since the project need to be execute on a vm with 1 processor and 4Go RAM.

To speed up my execution someone told me to change all the call from the object Sys.OleObject.

Example : I got a call like `xmlDoc.item(0);` I change it for `xmlDoc.$call("item", 0);`

same thing for the attribute : I got `xmlDoc.length` change to `xmlDoc.$get("length");`

This increase speed, but i would like to know why exactly, the person who told me to do it didn't know really why.

---

Because i got a problem since I made my change, when the file are big, sometime I got error like Log.Error or Log.PopLogFolder doesn't exist. And those function are Testcomplete function for logging.

Any thought on the reason of those errors?  Cause since the new call are faster I would like to keep them.

Answer (score 0):

TestComplete 12.0 was the first version that has JavaScript and, perhaps, there were some issues with it. Install the latest version which is 12.10 by the moment and, perhaps, these issues will gone.

As for the reason of the better speed with the changed calls, I think that the reason is that these methods are lower level methods comparing to the usual methods which produces some overhead.